# Drupal 7: Creating a taxonomy filter using checkboxes

Tags: drupal, drupal-taxonomy

I'm looking to create a page with a taxonomy filter using checkboxes and when one or more checkboxes is ticked this creates the list of pages below that are tagged with the chosen taxonomy. E.g The filter may contain categories A, B, C, D and E as checkboxes. If the user ticks Category A and Category D then clicks a submit button all pages that are associated to A and D will be listed below.

---

Seem to be struggling using both methods! Has anyone got a tutorial or step by step guide I could use? Otherwise, can someone help with the following questions?

1. I created the form in block--block--1.tpl.php by getting the taxonomy tags using taxonomy_get_tree(1); and looping through these to create the checkboxes. I was hoping I could then somehow get the post data and create a list of events (pages) which contain the tags selected. Where would I do the PHP for this? I'm guessing it wouldn't be within the template file so would it be in my custom module? If so, how?
2. I was thinking of creating a form and using hook_form_FORM_ID_alter but how do I create the form using the taxonomy tags? How do I then add this form into my block?
3. Any other options?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the excellent [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views). Views lets you create custom lists of content that you can set to be filtered by the user. There's a good article on building a filterable list with views here.

http://www.advomatic.com/blogs/amanda-luker/build-filterable-staff-directory-drupal-6-or-7

You should be able to easily adjust this tutorial to include checkboxes instead of drop downs.

Comment: How do I set it to be filtered by the user??

Comment: You have to make sure your view is a page and use the contextual filters.

Comment: Hmm, can't see any option in the dropdown for this? I assume I have to select 'Content: Has taxonomy term ID' but can't see any option to allow users to filter the results.

Comment: Right, im getting somewhere now. I was looking at the contextual filters under advanced rather than just 'Filter Criteria'. Now I just need to change the dropdown to checkboxes, hmm.

Comment: I've managed to change it to checkboxes, pretty easily in the end using:

Comment: Done, thanks. By the way, I've set them as checkboxes but for some reason they are automatically checked when I load the page. I assume I can change this in mymodule_form_alter but not sure what's causing them to be checked, any idea?

Comment: Thanks. You'll be able to hook into the form to change this.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be using a Faceted Search solution like http://drupal.org/project/facetapi. It works with any underlying search solution, including SOLR if you have big volumes.

Comment: Is there a demo of this up anywhere? Sounds quite interesting.

Comment: Don't know of demo, but this page http://wunderkraut.com/en/blog/get-wild-facets-%E2%80%93-extending-facet-api has interesting info, with a sample implementation and links to companion modules.

Answer (score 0):

TO change the filter from select to checkboxes I done the following:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

switch ($form_id) {
case 'views_exposed_form':
    $form['tid']['#type'] = 'checkboxes';
break;
    }
}
```